# wkhtmltopdf segfault when ran from python

Tags: python, subprocess, odoo, wkhtmltopdf

I have to run `wkhtmltopdf` from python with subprocess.call(...). From the command line, I can generate the pdf without problem but when its run from python, it fail with a segfault.

I have no idea what is causing `wkhtmltopdf` to segfault.

I even tried sending my terminal `env` attributes but it still segfaults. I sent stderr, stdin, stdout but nothing works. What's worrying me is that it runs from a terminal but not from python.

Also, calling the process from a different process in python also makes it segfault. For exemple, I added a script in between to call this application and the script written in python also receive a segfault from wkhtmltopdf.

```
#!/bin/env python
import subprocess
import sys
import pdb
import os


sys.argv[0] = "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.b"

sys.argv.remove('--quiet')

status = subprocess.call(sys.argv,
    env=env,
    stdin=sys.stdin,
    stdout=open("/tmp/stdout.w", "w"),
    stderr=open("/tmp/stderr.w", "w"))

cmd = " ".join(sys.argv)

pdb.set_trace()
```

Right now I'm doing this to get me time to execute the command in an external terminal. OpenErp is checking for the content of the pdf file. `wkhtmltopdf.b` is the original binary. I removed the quiet parameter as I wanted to see what's going on.

It apparently segfaults at this moment:

```
Loading pages (1/6)
[======>                                                     ] 10%
```

And nothing else

My version of wkhtmltopdf amd64 static from the website wkhtmltopdf.org

```
$ wkhtmltopdf -V
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.1 (with patched qt)
```

I'm running one of the ubuntu amd64 binary package on my gentoo box. It's kind of hard/long to get wkhtmltopdf compiled with patched qt on gentoo it doesn't seems to be supported by default. Yet, since it's running from the command line, it should also run from python.

I'm running it from zsh but even if inside my python program I would instead call something like this:

```
'/bin/sh -c "%s"' % command
```

It would also segfault.

Comment: Python's subprocess starts a new shell, which probably doesn't inherit a few shell settings & environment variables. For example, you could have a `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on your command line pointing to a newer library that `wkhtmltopdf` uses, while that path is lacking when started through `subprocess`, and thus `wkhtmltopdf` falls back to an older library, which causes the segfault. Try searching for one or more shell/environment variables that cause `wkhtmltopdf` to run properly on the command line.

Comment: @Evert I thought of that. I updated the `env` dict with the result of `env` from my terminal. I stripped it out because it's pretty big. But the env is the same as in my terminal.

Comment: Just to double check, print out your environment when run from the cmdline or when run from subprocess.

Comment: Can you list your Python version, OS, shell type & version, and wkhtmltopdf version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue as yours but running through a different stack (Apache & PHP) but I'm not 100% sure how you launch your python in fact. Anyway, it crashed exactly at the same place as yours and it was working fine from command line so I guess it may be worth sharing in case that helps anyone ;)

I found out my issue was an ulimit set differently when ran through apache then shell. Specifically my "virtual memory" ulimit -v was pretty low. I end up doing $cmd = "ulimit -v 1073741824; {$this->wkhtmltopdf_path}...." and that solves my issue! (You can check with running ulimit -a and compare the values from the same command on the shell!)

Comment: I'll have to try this.

Comment: Okay, can't say it's 100% right in my case because ulimit won't have any effect in odoo... but I changed the parameters that control memory usage and setting a ulimit to over 1gb of ram kind of fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the HTML string via stdin. Here's an example followed by a download response.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
from django.core.files.temp import NamedTemporaryFile
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.http import HttpResponse

tmp = NamedTemporaryFile()
html = render_to_string('your-template.html', context)
p = Popen(['wkhtmltopdf', '-', tmp.name], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
out, err = p.communicate(input=(html + u'\n').encode('utf-8'))
# check for errors in 'out' and 'err' -- print out, err
with open(tmp.name, 'r') as pdf:
    pdfcontent = pdf.read()
response = HttpResponse(pdfcontent, content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=print.pdf'
response['Content-Length'] = len(pdfcontent)
return response
```

You'll have to use full static URLs in your templates to prevent `wkhtmltopdf` from not finding the static CSS and JS files.